# Setting a padding / margin with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I set a padding with multiple values using jQuery?

This doesn't work:

```
$('#el').css({ 'padding': [top, right, bottom, left] });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space-separated values as a strings.

```
$('#el').css({ 'padding': '1px 2px 3px 4px' });
```

Comment: So `'padding': top+'px '+right+'px '+bottom+'px '+left+'px '`? Are the "px" mandatory? Or does jQuery take care of it?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('div').css(
    {
        'padding' : '5px 30px 6px 12px',
        'background-color' : '#fff'
    });
});
```